# I want to move to the new page of Fastreport

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

I am creating a report in FastReport. I am using 3 Main DataBands. The 2nd DataBand does not fit on the page and switches to a new page. There is no problem until here. However, it becomes merged with the page at the bottom.
What I want is to continue from the new page at the bottom.

I would be very grateful if you can help with this.

[image: Page1]

[image: Page2]

Comment: private void Data3_AfterPrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Report.Engine.StartNewPage();
    }

its worked.